# Laptop keyboard issues with spacebar and 'b' key

Tags: keyboard, firefox, 22.10

Recently Ubuntu 22.10 on my laptop has been having issues with the spacebar and 'b' keys.  To work around this intermittent issue I click the human symbol (top right) and have enable the virtual keyboard.  Spacebar and 'b' function on it.  The problem is such that I can login and use Firefox browser to do a Duolingo lesson with absolutely no issues and then suddenly a Google search from Firefox browser (most current version) will be missing the spacebar spaces and the 'b' key will be gone.  Is this a virus as there appears no physical problem with the keys (eg. sticky keys) on the keyboard and does anyone know how to permanently get rid of the issue as it is annoying?

I did add some other Keyboard layouts in the process of trying to get rid of the issue eg. en1, en2, es1, and es2.  Power down and restart now appears to temporarily get rid of the problem.

Comment: Usually this kind of problem is simply caused by a faulty or damaged keyboard, or dust on the connector for example. In the latter case, simply taking the laptop apart and putting it back together (unplugging and re-plugging the keyboard) can be enough to solve the issue.

Comment: One question per question. Questions about Ask Ubuntu itself should be asked on meta.askubuntu.com

Comment: I checked the keyboard and it doesn't appear to be faulty.  It would have been easier to understand if it had been.

Comment: How do you know the keyboard is not faulty? I am not saying the keyboard is definitely faulty, but it's the most likely and simple explanation.

Comment: I eliminated the 2nd question.  I combined the ones in the earlier paragraph as a virus or bug seems the most likely cause.  I've now set the F9 key to enable or disable the virtual keyboard.  I did ensure the system was completely up-to-date with upgrades.  The issue itself does affect any typed in passwords with a 'b' in them.

Comment: A bad keyboard connection would not make the keys sticky.

Comment: True.  But I did use canned air to dust off the keyboard (there was no dust but just in case).  There is no problem with the keyboard.  A bad connection would be a little weird allowing a question and comments plus a language class and then showing up on Firefox.

Comment: It would be time based, coming and going. Does it always not work in Firefox and always work fine in Duolingo? Because if that's the case then the hardware is fine and you're right, it is something to do with software.

Comment: I didn't want to chat.  But I tend to agree.  I use Google search in Firefox and once the problem started had to eliminate it with the virtual keyboard.  Once eliminated, Duolingo always works until Firefox and Google search is used and issue appears.